# Why in mysql store data like this a:6:{s:5:"title";s:43:}

Tags: php, mysql

In mysql database , I find some data store like below:

> a:6:{s:5:"title";s:43:"fgjfh";s:8:"province";s:6:"重庆";s:4:"city";s:9:"大渡口";s:8:"location";s:6:"fhfghf";s:9:"starttime";s:11:"09-02
>   12:00";s:7:"endtime";s:11:"09-02 16:00";}

Comment: As for the **why**; that we can only speculate about. But basically the database is used as a document storage. Serialized data blobs are appropriate if the database should never need to work with contained fields. Then avoiding the extra management overhead of separate tables/rows is sometimes welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a PHP [serialized](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) array. You serialized your array before putting it to the database.

Look for `serialize($value)` calls in your code if you want to change it.

*Update:*

Probably your stored data (which is a *hash* actually) has dynamic fields, and it was too difficult for the creator or he/she didn't care/was lazy to do so/decided that's not important or simply that was not the use case.

But you should consider to rethink your schema and create a correct (3NF) [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). In this case you will have at least one table which can be **like** this:

```
CREATE TABLE data (
  id          INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, -- or SERIAL if your database supports it
  title       VARCHAR,             -- or TEXT
  province_id INTEGER NOT NULL,    -- or REFERENCES the provinces table
  city_id     INTEGER NOT NULL,    -- or REFERENCES the cities table
  location    VARCHAR,             -- I do not really know what is this field
  starttime   TIMESTAMP,
  endtime     TIMESTAMP
);
```

And of course your you'll need the `provinces` and the `cities` tables as well. With this schema you could use database instructions to work with the stored data if you need so.

Comment: could you  explain in detail? Why not directly store the data?

Comment: @Charles, why is it horrible idea if it was not intended to be used in a query search?  For example in caching .

Comment: @Dreaded, caching is pretty much the *only* reason you'd ever want to consider storing PHP serialized data in a relational (or non-relational, really) database.